# An audio of the video starts playing before clicking the play button that pops up youtube video, and also after closing the video

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I need help with a code. The code I have has a play button, and when you click the button, it pops up a youtube video and automatically starts playing. The problem I have is that the audio of the video begins to play soon as I land on the page with the play button. Even after clicking the play button, and closing the video, the audio continues to play. I don't want the sound before the video is open or after the video is closed. Can someone help me with the code? What have I done wrong? I am writing this code on Squarespace code block for my website. I got this code from fiddle, and I customized the play button.

The link to fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/d1thm4cq/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=d1thm4cq

The code I have is as follows:

```
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3`enter code here`.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank">
  <span style="font-size: 32px; color: #36B3B3;">
<i class="fas fa-play"></i>
</span>
</a>
<div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sb1ZKzll6c4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#headerPopup{
width:75%;
margin:0 auto;
}

#headerPopup iframe{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

</body>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
type:'inline',
midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always  set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<iframe>` plays because the link contains `&autoplay=1`, regardless of whether the modal is open or not.

You need to remove autoplay from link, add it dynamically when you open the modal and remove it again when you close the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true,
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {
        const video = document.querySelector('#headerPopup iframe');
        video.src = video.src + (video.src.indexOf('?') < 0 ? '?' : '&') + 'autoplay=1';
      },
      close: function() {
        const video = document.querySelector('#headerPopup iframe');
        video.src = video.src.replace('&autoplay=1', '').replace('?autoplay=1', '');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Remember you also need to remove the `&autoplay=1` from the `<iframe>`s link.
Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/hwgsx928/).

Comment: Thank you so much...it works now!! Thank you, I really appreciate it